# WPF Firefox 4 Top Bar?

Tags: c#, wpf, firefox, xaml, hardware-acceleration

How would one create the top bar such as in Firefox 4's Orange bar?

I don't want to do my own window class as I still want to be hardware accelerated rather than sofware rendered.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: sorry but I have no idea which one is it. show a screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do your own Window drawing, with custom chrome, in order to achieve this type of effect.  Here is some [sample code showing the technique](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/chrome).

> I don't want to do my own window class as I still want to be hardware accelerated rather than sofware rendered.

With WPF, provided you're on a proper rendering tier, the window will still stay hardware accelerated, as WPF uses hardware acceleration for its rendering anyways.